# Laravel deeply nested relationship query returning incorrect results

Tags: laravel-5

So I am working with Laravel 5.4 and have combed stackoverflow and the web for answers to my problem. I am close but something is still not quite right. I am getting MOSTLY valid result sets but they are sprinkled with the odd incorrect record.

Following many suggestions online I am doing the following in my controller:

```
protected function index(Request $request) {
    $orderBy = $request->has('order_by') ? $request->get('order_by') : '';

    $query = Booking::sortable();

    // Limit result set to just the records for this reseller 
    // if the user is a reseller and not a full admin
    if (!empty(\Auth::user()->reseller_id)){
         $query->with(['delivery' => function($query){
            $query->where('delivery_option_type', 'reseller');

            $query->with(['delivery_option' => function($query){
                $query->where('reseller_id', \Auth::user()->reseller_id);
            }]);

            $query->has('delivery_option');
        }]);           
    }

    // Determine what query to run based on the selected booking list
    switch ($request->get('type')){
        case 'upcoming':
            $query->doesntHave('named_devices')
                ->orWhere('pickup_date', '>=', date('Y-m-d'));
            break;
        case 'active':
            $query->where('pickup_date', '<=', date('Y-m-d'))
                ->has('named_devices');
            break;
        case 'completed':
            $query->withoutGlobalScope(ActiveBookings::class)->ofState(BookingState::COMPLETE);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return $query->orderBy($orderBy)->paginate();
}
```

Booking Class has this:

```
public function delivery()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Delivery::class);
}
```

Delivery Class has this method:

```
public function delivery_option()
{
    return $this->morphTo(); // delivery_option_type is 'reseller'
}
```

Delivery Option Class has these methods:

```
public function reseller(){
    return $this->hasOne(Reseller::class);
}

public function deliveries()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Delivery::class, 'delivery_option');
}
```

In a list of roughly 50 results from the DB I have about 6 that are the incorrect reseller_id.

I notice that the above code seems to remove the reseller_option from the Bookings that have the incorrect reseller_id but it is not removing the Booking from the result set. The whole Booking needs to be removed.

Is there any reason this would not be reducing my set properly? Any other suggestions to make this work?

Comment: why select instead of where ?   `$subQuery->select('reseller_id', \Auth::user()->reseller_id);`

Comment: @AnarBayramov because using a where seems to give me an SQL error saying 'column not found' for reseller_id. And to be honest this was what most seemed to suggest online.

Comment: Pop by the office with your laptop so I can see more of what's going on.